# Rewriting a sum of a series without sigma

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$∑_{i=1}^ni=1+2+3+⋯+n$$ 
can be rewritten as $$\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{2}$$

Now, what can the following sum series be rewritten as, if your goal was to get rid of the sigma?

$$∑_{i=0}^{log(n)}2^i=1+2+4+8+⋯+n$$

Comment: Since $\log(n)$ is not an integer, you can't actually use it as a sum range. You can try $\sum_{i=0}^{m}$ and try a few values for $m.$ You might see a pattern.

Comment: $$\sum_{i=0}^m r^i=\frac{1-r^{m+1}}{1-r}$$

Comment: @mr_e_man how did you derive that`?

Comment: $$(a-b)(a^m+a^{m-1}b+a^{m-2}b^2+\cdots+b^m)=a^{m+1}-b^{m+1}$$

Comment: @mr_e_man what does a and b represent?

Comment: $a$ and $b$ are any numbers. This is a basic algebraic identity. Expand the left side, and you get the right side. Then plug in $a=1$ and $b=r=2$,...

Comment: @mr_e_man I am afraid I don't see the connection to my originally stated sum series. Could you elaborate on how you derived your expression from my sum series?

Comment: $$\sum_{i=0}^m 2^i=\frac{1-2^{m+1}}{1-2}=2^{m+1}-1.$$ And as Thomas said, $\log(n)$ doesn't make sense as a sum limit unless it's an integer $m$.

Comment: $$1+2=3=4-1\\1+2+4=7=8-1\\1+2+4+8=15=16-1$$

Comment: I think you want $n$ as the upper limit and $2^n$ as the final term.

Answer (score 1):

$n$ is a power of $2$. Then

$$S:=1+2+4+8+\cdots+n$$ is such that

$$2S=2+4+8+16+\cdots2n=S-1+2n$$

and

$$S=2n-1.$$

Answer (score 0):

I'm thinking that the upper limit on the $\Sigma$ is meant to represent logarithm base $2$, based on the terms on the right side.

In which case you can take

$$2\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2n}2^i - \left(\sum_{i=0}^{\log_2n}2^i\right) = \sum_{i=0}^{\log_2n}2^i = 2n-1.$$